# Do Java TCP streams have to be recreated after each connection?

Tags: java, java-me

I'm working on a J2ME application but it's likely socket behaviour is similar in J2SE and almost no one is using J2ME so I think it's worth understanding how J2SE does it.
When I send a TCP message, then receive a response, am I supposed to be unable to continue using the streams from the previous message sent? Must I go out of my way to destroy the previous connection and create a new one?

Comment: TCP is based on a stream concept, not a message concept. What do you mean by "send a TCP message"? Are you writing one message to the stream and closing the stream?

Comment: TCP sends segments with an implicit sequence number for each byte sent to allow for partial acknowledgement and reordering of segments prior to delivery.  TCP connections are not preserved and passed on to other applications within the destination host.  So new TCP sockets are created for new connections.  This does not mean that a single TCP connection can't last for hours.  It all depends on the application's requirements.

Comment: @Joni What I mean is that if I send something to the server, and then the server responds, after I have read the response should I discard the connection? It seems in practice that my connection just dies after I try to send more things and I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: "should I discard the connection" That's entirely up to you and how you have designed the communication protocol. If the protocol designed in a way that allows sending multiple requests and receiving multiple responses without danger of them running into each other, you can definitely reuse the connection.

Comment: Only if you are done transmitting and receiving data.  But it can be left open as long as you want.  An example is that a BGP TCP connection can remain established indefinitely.